# Refering to the key of data.table in "by" argument not using key()

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to refer the key of a data table in the argument `by` without using function `data.table::key`.

For example, I can do this:

```
x <- data.table(mtcars, key='cyl')
x[, .(mean=mean(mpg)), by=key(x)]

cyl     mean
1:   4 26.66364
2:   6 19.74286
3:   8 15.10000
```

But I want to do this:

```
x <- data.table(mtcars, key='cyl')
x[, .(mean=mean(mpg)), by=.KEY]

cyl     mean
1:   4 26.66364
2:   6 19.74286
3:   8 15.10000
```

Now, `.KEY` does not exists, but is there an alias for they key of data table at all? I was not able to find it in the documentation of data.table nor by searching the web.

Referring to the key of `x` with `.KEY` (or its equivalent) does not require me to know the variable name `x`. I don't know why exactly, but it does not feel right or elegant to use `key(x)`.

Comment: No, but I think that'd be a good feature request (see https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Support ). In the meantime, if you're willing to load magrittr, there's `x %>% .[, .(mean = mean(mpg)), by=key(.)]`

Comment: @Frank that's a confusing mash-up of dots hehe

Comment: As an example of where `.KEY` would be useful: `x[ , mean(mpg), keyby = .(cyl, am)][ , range(V1), by = .KEY[1L]]` -- basically, `key(x)` is no longer possible past the first link of a `[]...[]` chain

Answer (score 1):

So it seems from the comments that there is no such way.

I have submitted a feature request: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2130 for `.KEY`